# Building a simple operattion type calculator for two digits? stuck at error

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to MusCalculator")
print("For adding two no type add")
print("for mutiplying type multiply")
print("for subtraction type subtract")
print("for dividing type divide")

def add_numbers(x, y):
    if input == "addition":
        addition = x + y
        print addition

    if input == "multiply":
        multiply = x*y
        print multiply

    if input == "subtract":
        if x > y:
            sub = x - y
            print sub
        else:
            sub = y - x
            print sub

    if input == "divide":
        div = x / y
        print div
    else:
        print("Use me if you know me") 



x = input("First No.")
y = input("Second No.")
addition = x + y
c = input("Type Operation")

add_numbers(x, y)
```

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aafaq\workspace\python\project 1.py", line 34, in <module>
    c = input("Type Operation")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.5.5.201603221110\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize\sitecustomize.py", line 141, in input
    return eval(raw_input(prompt))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'addition' is not defined
```

Comment: `input` is a function - so you can't use it as a variable (which you haven't even defined). Pass `c` as an argument to `add_numbers` and use that to see what the user's choice was. Also, your `if` and `else` constructions seam messed up. Did you mean to use `elif` instead of the additional `if`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code. Some are mentioned below.
Addition variable is used in your main code, you might want to try different name or declare addition as a global variable.

under or above your print statements:
addition = 0

Also you are setting the received operation into variable name c, which is not referred anywhere, that should have been set to variable name input (which is a system define function name, you should not use that name to compare it with a string).

You are probably trying to do something like this:

```
operation = " "
addition = 0
def add_numbers(x, y):
    if operation == "addition":
        addition = x + y
        print addition

    if input == "multiply":
        multiply = x*y
        print multiply

    if operation == "subtract":
        if x > y:
            sub = x - y
            print sub
        else:
            sub = y - x
            print sub

    if operation == "divide":
        div = x / y
        print div
    else:
        print("Use me if you know me") 


x = input("First No.")
y = input("Second No.")
addition = x + y
operation = input("Type Operation")

add_numbers(x, y)
```

Comment: Some more things. First `operation` in  the function `add_numbers` is taken out of the global context. It would be better to provide this as an additional parameter. Second the name "add_function" is misleading, because this function does a lot more than just add two numbers. And of course the usage of `input` in Python 2 is dangerous. It would be better to use `raw_input` and cast the result with `int()` (where it's needed).

Comment: yes, a better approach will be to pass the operation parameter and change the function name as it doing a lot more than adding numbers.